# C# Cannot save textbox data to excel document

Tags: c#, excel, interop, oledb, excel-interop

As far as I know, there are no errors to speak of in the following code:

```
    private Excel.Application Xls;
    private Excel.Workbooks XlsB;
    private Excel.Workbook WB;
    private Excel.Worksheet WS;
    private Excel.Sheets WBs;

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Xls = new Excel.Application();
            XlsB = Xls.Workbooks;
            WB = XlsB.Open(lblPath.Text, 0, false, 5, "", "", true,
                XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Sheets WBs = WB.Worksheets;
            Worksheet WS = WBs.get_Item(1);
            WS.Cells[1, 1] = txtTATW.Text;
            WB.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Write Excel: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            releaseObject(WS);
            releaseObject(WBs);
            releaseObject(WB);
            releaseObject(XlsB);
            WB.Close(true, lblPath.Text, misValue);
            Xls.Quit();
            releaseObject(Xls);
        }
    }
```

Finally the release method:

```
        private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Some of the data is carried over from a different form, which is not visible here, but everything important should be listed!

It basically just pulls data from a textbox into a particular cell. For now, i'm testing it with only once cell.
Here's to hoping a second pair of eyes can help me find a solution.

Comment: When you say everything important should be listed, is, this not the complete code that your using?

Comment: @SimonPrice Right, well I mean the rest of the code belongs to the form which has other unnecessary stuff.

Comment: ok, so what happens when you debug this?

Comment: Nothing actually. No errors are thrown. Previously I noticed that Excel was running in the background even after I closed the application, which meant that the garbage collection was buggy. Now, I upgraded to an ACE connection from JET which means it should have less problems like these cause it doesn't really need to open Excel to function code. Now... it does nothing. No errors, nada. File isn't updated. @SimonPrice

Comment: I am confident you will get an error at line: `WB.Close(true, lblPath.Text, misValue);`… You have already released `WB` with `releaseObject(WB);` There wont be anything to close. That line and XLSs.Quit() should be closed and quit BEFORE you release them.

Comment: Got me excited it would work again for a second there @JohnG. I corrected the clear mistake but it's still refusing to work. No debug errors to speak of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the line ~WB.Close()~ before the release ~releaseObject(WB)~ The code changes cell[1,1] with some text. I changed the path and the text from the form, but the excel part saves properly. Hope this helps.

```
private Excel.Application Xls;
private Excel.Workbooks XlsB;
private Excel.Workbook WB;
private Excel.Worksheet WS;
private Excel.Sheets WBs;
string lblPath = "SomePath";
string txtTATW = "Some Text";

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    Xls = new Excel.Application();
    XlsB = Xls.Workbooks;
    WB = XlsB.Open(@"H:\ExcelTestFolder\TestAddData.xlsx", 0, false, 5, "", "", true,
        XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    WBs = WB.Worksheets;
    WS = WBs.get_Item(1);
    WS.Cells[1, 1] = txtTATW;
    WB.Save();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Write Excel: " + ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    WB.Close();
    Xls.Quit();
    releaseObject(WS);
    releaseObject(WBs);
    releaseObject(WB);
    releaseObject(XlsB);
    releaseObject(Xls);
  }
  MessageBox.Show("Finished Updating File");
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: ERMAHGERD I'm an idiot! I've been slaving over this for 4 hours trying different things and it turns out my print button isn't linked to any particular event! So when I click it, nothing happens! :D  God, that was stupid. But you did point out the garbage collector mistake, thanks very much for that my friend! Case closed. (It works)